# Strictly convex function, implies that translation is strictly convex.

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm wondering about this question. Prove that the function $f(x)=\|x\|^{2}$, and then answer.  If the function $f(x)=\|x\|^{2}$ is strictly convex implies that $f(x)=\|x-a\|^{2}$ is strictly convex? Where $a\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. I'm available to prove that $\|x\|^{2}$, but i'm not sure about of this question.

Can someone give me a light? Thanks.

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio, the statement was corrected.

Comment: If you have proved that $\| \cdot \|$ is strictly convex then the translation follows **immediately** from the defintion.

Comment: Thanks! @cooper.hat.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a strict convex function $f$, you can prove strict convexity of translation by doing something like
\begin{align*}
&f(tx + (1-t)y - a) \\
&= f(tx + (1-t)y - ta - (1-t)a) \\
&= f(t(x-a) + (1-t)(y-a)) \\
&< tf(x-a) + (1-t)f(y-a) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! @gst076923. I'm not sure if the two first lines in the proof are necessary. Thanks! again.